# How to make my code print out the inputted name?

Tags: c++, xcode

```
#include <iostream>
int name;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    std::cout << "What's Your Name?"<< std::endl;
    std::cin >> name;
    std::string text = "Hi ";
    std::cout << text << name << std::endl ;
    return 0;
}
```

it just outputs:

> What's Your Name?
>
> King
>
> Hi 0

Program ended with exit code: 0

Comment: You failed to check the return value of the input operation.

Comment: Storing a name as an integer? Hmm...

Comment: What should I store it in as?

Comment: What are you doing on the line `std::string text = "Hi ";`?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 problems with this code:

**Firstly**, you have declared `name` as an integer value, which is only used to store numbers, not string values. You should change the definition of `name` to:

```
std::string name;
```

**Secondly**, you have not included the header file for string. Include the header file:

```
#include <string>
```

**Another thing**: why have you defined the variable `name` as a global variable? It is not wrong, but it is better practice to declare your variable in the scope it is used; over here, it is used inside the `main()` function.

Comment: Will the downvoter of this answer provide a good reason for the downvote? I can fix my answer accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: I am not the one but I guess that's because of <string.h>

Comment: @Slava Thanks for pointing that out! Silly typo error on my part :)

Answer (score 0):

You have declared `name` as an int, yet are trying to store a string. Fixing that should fix the issue.

```
#include <iostream>
std::string name;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    std::cout << "What's Your Name?"<< std::endl;
    std::cin >> name;
    std::string text = "Hi ";
    std::cout << text << name << std::endl ;
    return 0;
}
```